# Dokku running same application on different domains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, vps, dokku

I'm trying to create two applications(NodeJS backend and ReactJS Frontend) using a VPS server with Dokku (mini Heroku) configured.
Basically, that's what i did so far:

- Created a folder for the project on my VPS server for my project
- Entered inside the folder previously created
- Executed the following command:

```
git clone:<project_url_backend>
```

- Then I entered the backend's folder created by the git clone command and then executed:

```
dokku apps:create backend-proj
git remote add dokku dokku@<my_ip>:backend-proj
git push dokku master
```

Everything looks fine until here and when I open the link that dokku created for the backend, it opens fine and I can use the backend correctly.

So I repeated the process for the frontend.

- Inside the project's folder, i run:

```
git clone:<project_url_frontend>
```

- I entered on the subfolder created by git and then run:

```
dokku apps:create frontend-proj
git remote add dokku dokku@<my_ip>:frontend-proj
git push dokku master
```

It builds fine, but when I open the created link for the frontend project, it opens the backend, not the frontend.

*Ps: I had issues with the react project(frontend), so I had to fix the Procfile, and run the frontend project by a server.js with express.js, serving the react application. I don't know whether this might have some influence on the process but I had to say anyway*

Answer (score 0):

### The problem was that I needed to put express.js as one of the required dependencies inside the package.json file. Then I recreated the application on Dokku and then it worked fine